# Is the order of the bundles/apps/plugins inside the generated file var/plugins.json in Shopware 6 important?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When developing store bundles/apps/plugins in Shopware 6, the file `var/plugins.json` often has to be generated since it is needed for the build scripts, for example `bin/build-administration.sh` in the Shopware 6 production template.

Depending on the branch that is being worked on, different bundles/apps/plugins are active. The file `var/plugins.json` is of course different in each branch, but the order of contents is constantly changing since the `bundle:dump` command has no integrated sorting which leads to repeated merge conflicts similarly to the composer.lock file, since the order of items changes most of the time.

A possible solution is to `ksort` the array of bundles/apps/plugins before it gets written into `var/plugins.json`. However, I'm wondering if this could lead to problems, for example should one plugin be dependent on another. So my question is: Is the order of the bundles inside the generated file `var/plugins.json` in Shopware 6 important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugins are sorted ascending by the date stored in `plugin.installed_at`. This affects the order of template inheritance within plugins for example, so generally speaking it matters. Within the `plugins.json` however I'm not exactly sure if it does though, since it seems to be used by the [`webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/ed95de5ce9a08627a3e450eb52f52cf24c5d054f/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/webpack.config.js#L465) for injecting a possible [custom webpack config of a plugin](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/extending-webpack), which I *think* should not come in conflict with each other no matter what the order is.